# Currying with functions that take unlimited arguments

Tags: javascript

Lets say i have the following add function that takes an unlimited number of arguments.

```
function add () {
    var total = 0;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        total += arguments[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

and the following curry function.

```
function curryFunction(orig_func) {
    var ap = Array.prototype;
    var args = arguments;
    function fn() {
        if (arguments.length != 0) {
            ap.push.apply(fn.args, arguments);
            return fn;
        } else {
            return orig_func.apply(this, fn.args);
        }
    };
    return function() {
        fn.args = ap.slice.call( args, 1 );
        return fn.apply( this, arguments );
    };
}
```

I then want to do something like:

```
var f = curryFunction(add);
var a = f(3)(4)(3);
var b = f(10)(3);
var result1 = a(); // returns 10
var result2 = b(); // returns 13
```

However i always get 13 for both a() and b() i assume is because in line

```
fn.args = ap.slice.call(args, 1);
```

the existing array [3,4,3] is overwriting with []. Can someone please provide me with a hint on how to make this work? Thanks

Comment: What is `fn.args` supposed to be? *edit* oh wait I see

Comment: How would you tell it when to stop returning the function and give you the actual result?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy i guess that's the question, can something like that be done using currying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `fn` is scoped to `curryFunction` and so is shared between `a` and `b`.

All you have to do is move the definition of `fn` into the anonymous return function. It's then created when you call `f`, and the problematic `fn.args =` line is only called once.

Proof: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLLJ5/).

Answer (score 3):

Currying a function which takes indefinitely many arguments can be implemented as follows;

Lets say we have a function called `addAll()` which returns the sum of all provided arguments.

```
var addall = (...a) => a.reduce((p,c) => p + c);
```

And we have a curry function which takes a function and returns curried version *ad infinitum* up until the returned function is called with no arguments, only when the result of all previously provided arguments will be returned. OK here is the `curry` function.

```
 var curry = f => (...a) => a.length ? curry(f.bind(f,...a))
                                     : f();
```

Lets see it in action;

```js
var addAll = (...a) => a.reduce((p,c) => p + c),
     curry = f => (...a) => a.length ? curry(f.bind(f,...a)) : f(),
   curried = curry(addAll),
    result = curried(10,11)(10)(37)(10,17,42)();
console.log(result);
result = curried("a","b")("c")("d")("e","f","g")();
console.log(result);
```